# How to load multiple svelte components dynamically?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have a svelte component for `Address` and user can add multiple addressees (primary, secondary, other etc) by clicking a button. I dont know upfront how many addresses user will add. I am struggling to model this with Svelte. The closest thing I have found is `svelte:component` but that only allows loading one component at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep all the addresses in an array and render an `Address` component for each element in this array and keep the element updated with e.g. an event emitted from the component.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3923862b41e748d1b1ca53ece88cafc3?version=3.16.4))**

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import Address from './Address.svelte';
  let addresses = [''];

  function addAddress() {
    addresses = [...addresses, ''];
  }

  function changeAddress(address, index) {
    addresses = addresses.map((a, i) => (i === index ? address : a));
  }
</script>

{#each addresses as address, index}
  <Address value="{address}" on:change="{e => changeAddress(e.target.value, index)}" />
{/each}

<button on:click="{addAddress}">Add address</button>

<!-- Address.svelte -->
<script>
  export let value = '';
</script>

<div>
  <input {value} on:change />
</div>
```